# Loading Data From Datagridview To TextBox

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am trying to load data from the DataGridview to the Textbox But it keeps giving me error

I have a DatagridView that loads some data when form loads, It contains six(6) Columns of data loaded from the database.
Once i click on any row, it should display the contents of the Row to TextBoxes available.

I keep getting the error "index was out of range must be nonnegative and less than the size of the collection parameter index"

```
      Try

        Dim current_row As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        txt_Prod_ID.Text = DataGridView1(0, current_row).Value
        txtprodname.Text = DataGridView1(1, current_row).Value
        txt_Barcode.Text = DataGridView1(2, current_row).Value
        txt_barcode2.Text = DataGridView1(3, current_row).Value
        txt_barcode3.Text = DataGridView1(4, current_row).Value
        txt_barcode4.Text = DataGridView1(5, current_row).Value

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
    End Try
```

I expect that when i click on any row, it should display the content in the Textboxes. Please assist.

Comment: You can bind the TextBoxes to the same DataSource used to fill the DGV. See [Control.DataBindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.databindings)

Comment: Works for me. Only with Option Strict On there is a compile error. Need to convert Object to String. Adding `.ToString` after `.Value` will fix that. You really need to turn Option Strict On now and in the future. It will help you avoid runtime errors. But this error doesn't seem to be caused by this. What line does it error on?

Comment: What event is this code in?

Comment: @mary, the event is Cellclick. Also some of the data in the datagridview could be empty

Comment: If I want to get for just two textboxes, it displays it well but anything above 2 textboxes

Comment: As suggested by @Jimi, you should not be using code for this at all.  Retriev the data from your database into a `DataTable`, bind that to a `BindingSource` and then bind that to the grid and the `TextBoxes`.  When you then select a row in the grid, the `TextBoxes` will be automatically populated with the data in that row.  Any changes you make to the data in the `TextBoxes` will be automatically pushed back to the `DataTable` and reflected in the grid.  No code required.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me. I have null values in some columns which just leave the text boxes empty.

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    Dim current_row As Integer = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Debug.Print(current_row.ToString)
    TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1(0, current_row).Value.ToString
    TextBox2.Text = DataGridView1(1, current_row).Value.ToString
    TextBox3.Text = DataGridView1(2, current_row).Value.ToString
    TextBox4.Text = DataGridView1(3, current_row).Value.ToString
End Sub
```

I am loading the grid in the form load by calling the following sub.

```
Private Sub FillBuildersGrid()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.BuildersConnectio)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Builders", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I will Try this as well

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of any cells, whether it is dbnull, empty or "", may be can use this method:

```
    If IsDBNull(DataGridView1(0, current_row).Value) Then
       TextBox1.Text = ""
    Else
       TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1(0, current_row).Value.ToString
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, using a `BindingSource` will “automatically” do this for you if the text boxes are set up properly. It is possible for this to work using the `DataTable` itself, however, the example below uses a `DataTable` as a `DataSource` to a `BindingSource` and uses the `BindingSource` as a `DataSource` to the `DataGridView` AND it is also used as a `DataBinding` to the `TextBoxes.`

When “binding” the `TextBox`’s, each text box will need to identify which “column” in the `BindingSource` to “bind” to. Then when the user selects a cell/row in the grid, the text boxes will change to match the “selected” row in the grid. Obviously, if the user has the option to “multiselect,” then, the text boxes will display the last selected row.

Note: the binding source will “update” when the “selected row” CHANGES. Meaning that if you change a value in the grid and then select another cell in the “same” row… the text boxes will not update. One possible solution is to wire up the grids cell value changed event to simply “reset” the binding source. This will update the text boxes regardless which cell is selected.

In this example, it is possible to change the text in the text boxes and it will be reflected/updated in the grid, however, it may/will be necessary to reset the binding source if the text changes and the user “leaves” the cell.

The code below should properly “Bind” the `TextBox`’s to a column in the `BindingSource` (GridBinding).

```
Private Sub BindTextBoxes()
    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", GridBinding, "ID"))
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", GridBinding, "Name"))
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", GridBinding, "Barcode"))
    TextBox4.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", GridBinding, "Barcode2"))
    TextBox5.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", GridBinding, "Barcode3"))
End Sub
```

A small example using the above method is shown below.

```
Dim GridTable As DataTable
Dim GridBinding As BindingSource

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    GridTable = GetTable()
    FillTable(GridTable)
    GridBinding = New BindingSource()
    GridBinding.DataSource = GridTable
    DataGridView1.DataSource = GridBinding
    BindTextBoxes()
End Sub

Private Function GetTable() As DataTable
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Barcode", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Barcode2", GetType(String))
    dt.Columns.Add("Barcode3", GetType(String))
    Return dt
End Function

Private Sub FillTable(dt As DataTable)
    For index = 1 To 15
        dt.Rows.Add("C0R" + index.ToString(), "C1R" + index.ToString(), "C2R" + index.ToString(), "C3R" + index.ToString(), "C4R" + index.ToString())
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged
    GridBinding.ResetBindings(False)
End Sub
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this, I will try it.